# How to change the tableviewcell 's backgroundimage?

Tags: objective-c, ios4

when I selected row, change the backgroundimages?

Answer (score 2):

```
        #define kCellHeight 50  //Replace '50' with Height of your UITableViewCell
        #define kSelectedCellBackgroundImage @"nameOfYourImage" //replace value inside "" with name of your image

        UIImageView *selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, kCellHeight)];
        [selectedBackgroundView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:kSelectedCellBackgroundImage]];
        [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:selectedBackgroundView];
        [selectedBackgroundView release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the `selectedBackgroundView` of `UITableViewCell` to your custom view.

Comment: PhraseSelectedCellViewController *phrView=[[PhraseSelectedCellViewController alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 60)];                                [cell.contentView addSubview:phrView]; cell.selectedBackgroundView=phrView;
 [phrView release];   is ok?